# Move additional information from product tab under product price or above add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

in single product pages, I would like to change the location of "additional information" from tabs, under product price or above add to cart button using Woocommerce hooks (removing the "additional information" tab).

I tried the following code but it appears under the button

```
// Remove additional information tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_additional_information_tab', 100, 1 );
function remove_additional_information_tab( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);

    return $tabs;
}

// Add "additional information" after add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart', 35 );
function additional_info_under_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change a priority.

> $priority     (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the
> functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower
> numbers correspond with earlier execution and functions with the same
> priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
> action.
>
> Default value: 10

Try the below code.

**Add `20` to show before add to cart.**

```
// Add "additional information" after add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart', 20 );
function additional_info_under_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

[image]

**Add `10` to show after price**

```
// Add "additional information" after add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart', 10 );
function additional_info_under_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for...

Thank you very much with all my heart

Comment: I have a question... 

What is the variable that can be used to cancel the appearance of some attributes in the additional information field..